# Gzipped CSS/JS/HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, gzip

I've heard about this recently, and I have a few questions:

1. Does any browser support this?
2. What happens if a browser doesn't support it, are they left unloaded?
3. Can I use this feature on a shared hosting using Apache and PHP5?
4. How can I use this feature?

P.S. It'd be related to Wordpress, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Browsers send a `Accept-Encoding` request header which will make it clear to the server whether compression is supported. Good news is *almost all popular browsers support it*
2. Server responds to the request based on if the browser supports gzip (i.e. if the `Accept-Encoding` request header contains `gzip` in it). If it is supported, the server responds with gzipped content - indicated by the `Content-Encoding` response header.
3. Check [**this**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) for how you can configure output compression on Apache HTTPD - Note you'll need to be able to edit the config file, which you may not be, since you are on a shared hosting server.
4. Configuring mod_deflate on Apache is all you need to do to start using this feature. It will take care of checking the `Accept-Encoding` request header and responding accordingly. *Make sure you do not force compression by using force-gzip* - You can find details regarding this on the link above.